# VSCODE intellisense not picking up css code in jsx file

Tags: css, reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, syntax-highlighting

I have been trying to figure out why vs code is not picking up CSS language inside the JSX file. When I'm writing CSS IntelliSense does not offer suggestions for CSS it only shows emmet suggestions.[image: snapshot of jsx file]

I have downloaded different extensions like **JS JSX Snippet or styled-jsx** hoping I am missing an extension and they did not work. In the video that I'm following on youtube, inside the BoxContainer the key and value `width:280px` for the CSS code have different colors to mine where mine is just brown throughout, for the instructor it's aqua and mint.

Comment: Check the [emmet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) settings in your copy of VScode. You probably need to enable or include CSS in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `styled-components`. There's an extension to VSCode to syntax highlight that style code (since it's not really SASS).

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components

Answer (score 0):

Path-intellisense extension by Christian Kohler works great for suggesting path completion with .css

Just disable the built-in path auto-complete function in settings. Add these two lines.

```js
 "typescript.suggest.paths": false ,
 "javascript.suggest.paths": false
```